# I want to remove certain parent- and child-divs in all my wordpress posts with php or some other script

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, wordpress

Is there a quick way, via script maybe, to remove a certain pair of div's out of all my wordpress posts? For example:

I want to go from this:

```
<div class="single_textimage">
<div class="youtube_play"><iframe src="-,-"></iframe></div>
<div class="single_textimage_text">Some text.</div>
<div class="single_textimage_copyright">Some text.</div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="youtube_play"><iframe src="-,-"></iframe></div>
```

> AND

From this:

```
 <div class="single_textimage">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1700" src="-,-" />
<div class="single_textimage_text">Some text.</div>
<div class="single_textimage_copyright">Some text.</div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1700" src="-,-" />
```

So I want the divs: single_textimage, single_textimage_text and single_textimage_copyright to go.

I hope there is an easy script, or difficult for that matter. Via "php", "mysql" or "jquery" for example, that I can put in test.php in the root or something...

I hope I supplied you with enough information. If I haven't made myself clear enough, please reply. :)

Comment: Maybe there is some relevance to mysql here not sure

Comment: I'm sorry @AsConfused , I don't completely understand your question.

Comment: You mention mysql trying to tie it in. If the above is in a mysql table now, can u show table schema

Comment: a possibility is load a bunch of files into the like of Visual Studio and do global Find and Replace. Don't over engineer it

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you should be able to take those out of whatever template your using - probably in a PHP include, but I don't really use WordPress, so I wouldn't know where without seeing all your files. If you're bent on using jQuery instead of modifying the template, I would throw in some CSS too, to hide the elements that will be removed:

```
.single_textimage, .single_textimage_text, .single_textimage_copyright{
    display:none;
}
```

Then you can take the elements you want to keep out of their parent DIVs, and place them right after (or before):

```
$('.youtube_play, .wp-image-1700').each(function(){
   $(this).parent().after($(this)); 
});
```

Then you can remove the elements you don't want from the page:

```
$('.single_textimage, .single_textimage_text, .single_textimage_copyright').remove();
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3uztorzL/

Answer (score 0):

I would use this search and replace utility to update all of the content in the DB:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

You'll need a regex to replace `<div class="single_textimage_text">Some text.</div>` (assuming the "some text" is different in each post). The utility supports regex replace. This may do it:

```
<div class="single_textimage_text">(.*?)</div>
```

Make sure you **make a backup** before you do the replace.